# What will the observer see when a person in a looming effect falls?

Tags: optics, refraction

[image]

[image]

So the above are the famous pictures of boats hovering over water, and below is the explanation of these phenomena.

[image]

I'm curious what would happen if a person falls from this boat.

1. Would a person disappear in the air, and his head float on the water afterward?
2. Or would a person appear to drop much faster, and the observer will see the whole process (until he falls into the sea)?